# Newbie to Newbie Ajax tips for ugly Invoice webpage

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-interface, master-detail, invoice

Some assorted pseudotips about "invoice oriented" master/detail web sites,

Examples (but with small detail) and highlights:

- The demo at [SimplyInvoices](http://www.simpleinvoices.org/demo/): the 5 blank items editable without a modal popup detail
- http://freelanceswitch.com/money/7-online-invoicing-apps-for-freelancers/ has some interesting web sites

Questions:

- Large products lookup search: this examples have a few items in a dropdown combo, and even search the product scrolling without typing (a fast google-filtering combo search?)

  - Answer: AJAX AutoComplete Extender (http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) and its use with ID key value (http://blogs.msdn.com/phaniraj/archive/2007/06/19/how-to-use-a-key-value-pair-in-your-autocompleteextender.aspx)
- Large detail?

  - Answer: Modal Popup + Gridview + UpdatePanel http://forums.asp.net/p/1007665/1339633.aspx Some headaches but still trying.
- How to distribute a lot  of controls a its validators, without needing too much scrolling? The AJAX control CollapsiblePanel? Or just avoid too much controls?

Lovely Blog: http://mattberseth.com/

Answer (score 1):

Hi if your new programming with ASP.net you will probably would like to check the Microsoft's MSDN site here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336613.aspx to some design templates that I think could help you.

I hope this works for you

Comment: those seemed to me generic templates, and i am worried specifically by the grid/items/details question. Thanks anyway